# Zero cash buying power, what would margin maintenance be?

Tags: margin, leverage, maintenance, margin-call

I have $0 cash buying power but have loads of margin buying power because of my current marginable securities. If I make a margin trade for any amount does that mean I have 0% equity in that position and my maintenance level would be at the exact price of execution, which would lead to any drop in stock price resulting in a house call?

Comment: Rules vary from broker to broker.  You may have more luck discussing this with their help desk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fully paid marginable securities can be used to buy additional securities on margin.  The formula for this is:

[ (Securities Value) x Margin % ] / [ (100% - Margin %) ]

In the US, Reg T initial margin is 50% so if you put up $10k of securities then you could buy another $10k of securities ($10k x .50 ) / (100% -50%)

In the US, maintenance margin is set is 25%.  Brokerage firms can require more.  this means that  there must be a minimum amount of equity valued at 25% or more of the total value of the margin account.

If the maintenance level is 25% then the Maintenance level is 4/3 x the Debit Balance. In  this example, 4/3 of $10k would be $13,333.  This level would be reached after you lost 1/3 of your portfolio value (2/3 x $20k).  At this point you would have:

$13,333 Market Value

$10,000 Debit

$ 3,333 Equity

The margin is $3,333 / $13,333 = 25%.  Any drop below $13,333 in position value would incur a margin call.